# swipe image click on right button and left button in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie to `IOS` programming and currently i have a image application with swipe images on `uiview`. I have questions.

i want to swipe image to right when click on right `button` and swipe image to left when click left `button` in iphone. 
 i am using this code:-

.h file

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface flashViewcontroller : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pageViews;

@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *next;

@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *previous;

-(void)loadVisiblePages;

-(void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;

-(void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page;

-(IBAction)next:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)previos:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)skipes:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: Show us what you try so far? what is the problem you face?

Comment: need not to share .h, share you .m file.

Answer (score 0):

// Left Button Click

```
-(IBAction)click_LeftBtn:(id)sender{
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(imgView.frame.orign.x, imgView.frame.orign.y, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];  //// Set Animationt time Duration
       [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, imgView.frame.orign.y, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
       [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

// Right Button Click

```
-(IBAction)click_RightBtn:(id)sender
{
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(imgView.frame.orign.x, imgView.frame.orign.y, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];  //// Set Animationt time Duration
       [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(320-imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.orign.y, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
       [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```